# Are there any known plans for the future of Leo Frankowski's Boy and his Tank series?

Tags: a-boy-and-his-tank, leo-frankowski

Leo Frankowski had an ongoing series, *A Boy and his Tank*, the last of which introduced an enemy (Kren of the Michegai) meant to be absolutely unrelatable; literal baby-eating monsters. And then Frankowski died, and of course the series was left hanging.

Are there any known notes or indications of his plans for where the series would go? If so, what were they?